# Rename array key without scrambling order

Tags: php

In PHP, I can easily rename an associative array's key by doing the following.

```
$array = array(
    "tom" => "25",
    "bob" => "36",
);

$array["charlie"] = $array["tom"];
unset($array["tom"]);
```

However, this scrambles the order of the array. "bob" becomes the first element and "charlie" (which was "tom") is now the second element.

```
echo reset($array); // outputs 36 instead of 25
```

Is there a way to rename an array key without scrambling its order?

NOTE: I realize I can reconstruct the array, but that is really ugly. I would much rather avoid that.

Comment: you said `"charlie" (which was "tom")` but your code: `$array["charlie"] = $array["bob"];`, I dont understand

Comment: Don't know why; but dictionary type arrays have no meaning either sorted or unsorted. You can display them however you like.

Comment: @hjpotter92, in PHP arrays are ordered as well.

Comment: @Jueecy.new This is a duplicate. Guess I didn't search enough. Thank you.

Comment: @gluxon, you should delete this question and save the mod the trouble. :)